# How to add scrollbars in c# form

Tags: c#, textbox, scroll

For some reason only adding a vertical scroll bar works with my code.

I can't seem to add BOTH a vertical ***and horizontal*** scroll bar.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;     
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: You want [ScrollBars.Both](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbars.aspx)

Comment: Your title says add scrollbar in form but code shows in textbox?

Comment: textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;     is set every time the character pressed inside text window. Remove this silly code

Answer (score 20):

You have to set both `ScrollBars` and `WordWrap` like this:

```
textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
textBox1.WordWrap = false;
```

**NOTE**: All the settings above are done 1 time. No need to place the code in the `TextChanged` event handler.

Comment: Weird, This still gives me just the Vertical Scrollbar, and continues to wrap strings to long to fit into one line.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to write a code for this. Just change the properties of textBox. For both scroll bars, if Multiline set to True, then  set ScrollBars to Both and set WordWrap to False in properties. No need for writing code at all since this is for WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;     
}
```

ScrollBars.[Value] is an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbars.aspx): Valid values are Horizontal, Vertical, None, and Both.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested but now I have no scroll bars. Strange ?

Comment: @user2788405 have you checked out my solution? Looks like you even don't know where to put my code?

Comment: @user2788405 try putting some text in there. You should also make sure that TextMode is set to MultiLine.

Comment: @KingKing appreciate your help. I did exactly what you told me too. Made a newtextbox, and copy pasted your code into my main. I imported a textfile that's too large horizontally and vertically in my textbox but I see no scroll bars. Thanks for the help

Comment: It's set to multiline

Comment: @user2788405 where did you post my code? It should be somewhere like in your form constructor.

Comment: @user2788405 in fact, you don't need to copy and paste the text into your textbox to **see the scrollbars**, the scrollbars should be visible with my code (although they look like **disabled**).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Vertical ScrollBar in your Form. Then copy and paste this code in *Form* **LOAD EVENT**. like

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VScrollBar vScroller = new VScrollBar();
        vScroller.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        vScroller.Width = 30;
        vScroller.Height = 200;
        vScroller.Name = "VScrollBar1";
        this.Controls.Add(vScroller);
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Drag and drop vertical or horizontal scroll bars from ToolBox onto the form. Dock to right and bottom.

Alternatively code location and size in Form_Load and Form_Resize. Another way is to use `GDI32`. If `GDI32` is used you don't need to add scroll bars from the `ToolBox` or programmatically. Call `SetScrollRange` and `SetScrollPos` in Form_Load and Form_Resize. Scrollbar attached to form will appear automatically. Suggest using SetScrollInfo in GDI32 to create proportional scrollbar. If you do not call SetScrollInfo a non-proportional scrollbar will be created. This is a scrollbar where the thumb size stays constant as window resizes.

Comment: Provide code to support your text. All I see is a lot of letters jumbled into one paragraph.